# Copying permissions from one mysql database to another

Tags: mysql, database-permissions

I would like to replicate the permissions from one database to another. Could that be done by simply copying the mysql table over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/8860/how-can-i-export-the-privileges-from-mysql-and-then-import-to-a-new-server) on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/8860/how-can-i-export-the-privileges-from-mysql-and-then-import-to-a-new-server).

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

I think your best bet is to query `information_schema` tables (`SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES, TABLE_PRIVILEGES, USER_PRIVILEGES`) and use this data to create `GRANT` queries

See more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privilege-system.html